# how can i set center (70%) croped image in imageview

Tags: android

I am facing one issue. issue is that i can not set 70% center part of image and image comes from server(url) so how can i set it in image view (in list). can you please suggest me how can i fix this.

here is the screen shot what i need

[image]

Here is the original image

[image]

and while i set image its display like

[image]

Thanks...

Comment: Set padding to the parent..

Comment: but sir image is coming from URL. and by padding it ll just decrease image size and i need display 70% portion of image in image view.

Comment: u might want to set scale type to image view as CENTER_CROP

Comment: @ay89 i set it. but not working

Comment: u need to set/adjust the dimensions of image view & its parent as well. can u share the code/xml where u are defining the image view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **Center Scale** your image. This can be achieved using :

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Apply scaling in X and Y direction for displaying 70% image. For displaying 70% image, image should be **scaled up**

```
android:scaleX="1.3f"
android:scaleY="1.3f"
```

You can check by changing `1.3f` value